# Every combination of elements in two Ruby arrays

Tags: ruby

I have three Ruby arrays:

```
color = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow']
names = ['jack', 'jill']
combination = []
```

I need the following concatenation inserted into the `combination` array:

```
FOR EACH names value: [name value] + " wants " + [color value]
```

So the outcome will be:

```
combination = ['jack wants blue','jack wants green','jack wants yellow','jill wants blue','jill wants green','jill wants yellow']
```

I can't figure out how to do this. I've tried this to start off with but no avail:

```
name.each do |name| 
   puts "#{name} wants #{color}"
end
```

Comment: What's the rush in selecting an answer? Quick selections tend to discourage other answers and is a bummer for those still preparing their answers when the greenie flashes on.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - I apologize, that was certainly not my intention. I tested and it worked to suit my needs, I thought it would benefit more if I selected quickly..

Comment: You needn't apologize. There are different opinions about how long one should wait before selecting an answer. Those new to SO haven't really thought about it and are anxious to show their appreciation for a good answer. btw,I wasn't implying that I was preparing an answer. (I had nothing useful to add.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Array#product`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Array.html#method-i-product):

```
names = ['jack', 'jill']
colors = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow']

names.product(colors).map { |name, color| "#{name} wants #{color}" }
#=> ["jack wants blue", "jack wants green", "jack wants yellow", "jill wants blue", "jill wants green", "jill wants yellow"]
```

Comment: Or `names.product(colors).map { |arr| arr.join(" wants ") }` if you don't want to splat and interpolate.

Answer (score 2):

Interpolation would work as in other answers, but I like string format better in cases like this. The `freeze` method is for optimization. It will also work without it.

```
names.product(colors).map{|a| "%s wants %s".freeze % a}
```

Comment: +1, I would use this if order was not important, e.g. `"%s vs. %s"`

Answer (score 0):

```
names = ['jack', 'jill']
colors = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow']
# Note - renamed to "colors" plural
names.collect { |name| colors.collect { |color| "#{name} wants #{color}" } }.flatten

=> ["jack wants blue", "jack wants green", "jack wants yellow", "jill wants blue", "jill wants green", "jill wants yellow"]
```